# Photoshop: Script to convert jpeg to 16 bit on open

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-script

Using Photoshop, I want to automatically convert all opened JPEGs to 16 bit. I currently do this manually before making any edits to them, and I figure I should be able to automate this step so it happens automatically.

I've learnt that I can run scripts on events using **Scripts Event Manager**, so I know how to run a script on document open.

But unfortunately I don't know how to write the Photoshop script itself.

Can anyone assist with how I'd write a script that detects whether the current document is RGB/8bit, and if it is, converts it to RGB/16bit, automatically on document open?

Alternatively, if there's any easier way to do this using Actions or something, that'd be good to know.

Comment: You can use Actions in the events manager, it's pretty straightforward. Check the `File > Scripts > Scripts Events Manager...`

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I missed that and thought it could only use scripts!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After deciding to not be lazy and look into it myself... it turns out it is not difficult.

This script will convert the active document to 16bit *if* it ends in *.jpg or *.jpeg, is an RGB document, and is 8 bit.

Changing these if conditions is easy as you can see below.

Save it as a .js or .jsx file.

Then to run this script automatically on file open, use **File** → **Scripts** → **Script Events Manager** and choose **Open Document** as the **Photoshop Event**, then select or browse for your script.

```js
if(
    /jp.?g$/i.test(activeDocument.name)
    && activeDocument.mode == DocumentMode.RGB
    && activeDocument.bitsPerChannel == BitsPerChannelType.EIGHT
) {
    activeDocument.bitsPerChannel = BitsPerChannelType.SIXTEEN;
}
```